# Laravel select only distinct value from a related model (Many to Many relationship)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

Its a hotel booking app, 1 hotel may have many rooms, one room may have many amenities (facilities).

**My models are like this:**

***Room Model:***

```
class Room extends Model
{

    public function amenities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Amenities')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function hotel(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Hotel');
    }

}
```

***Amenities Model:***

```
class Amenities extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function rooms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Room')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

I can able to get the each rooms amenities with below query:

```
$room = Room::with('amenities')->with('roomtype')
                        ->with('image')->Where('hotel_id', $hotel->id)->get();
```

This will give amenities for each room, so i can loop through each rooms and get the amenities

```
@foreach($room as $row)
    @foreach($row->amenities as $amenity)
        {{ $amenity->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The problem:
I want distinct *amenities*, for example many rooms may have *wifi* amenity. but i want it for only one time? how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `whereHas()` method:

```
$amenities = Amenities::whereHas('room', function($q) use($hotel) {
    $q->where('hotel_id', $hotel->id);
})
->get();
```

Or, you can use loaded data. Just tested this, works perfectly:

```
$amenities = $room->pluck('amenities')->flatten()->unique('id');
```

Comment: just removed a spelling mistake and it works awesome. *user($hotel)* to *use($hotel)*

Comment: You are the pro man, second one is awesome, i never expected pluck will pluck from 'related models' collection